# Placeholders in bash script for firewall

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, placeholder

i want to write function, that will make:

1. reading text from file in a loop
2. executing command

I have a command

```
for BAD_INPUT_IP in `grep -v ^# /etc/rc.d/bad_input.ip`; do
iptables -I INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP
done
```

I want to rebuild this to function:

```
function go_loop (){
for BAD_INPUT_IP in `grep -v ^# $1`; do
        iptables -I INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP
done
}

go_loop "/etc/rc.d/bad_input.ip"
```

First part of task i made. Everything is ok. But how to make placeholder for this command ?

`iptables -I INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP`

I will have a lot of different commands, where i will need a loop. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable before running going to the function

```
function go_loop (){
for BAD_INPUT_IP in `grep -v ^# $file`; do
        iptables -I INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP
done
}

file="/etc/rc.d/bad_input.ip"
go_loop
```

Comment: sorry, but i want to do something like that:
`go_loop "/etc/rc.d/bad_input.ip" "iptables -I INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP"`

Comment: @Piduna, I question why you want to do this. Please update your question to explain. It is inefficient to call go_loop multiple times instead of putting all the commands into the same loop.

Comment: i will use different commands:
opening ports;
opening access to ip addresses;
etc..
it will not work