# Expansion of variable does not work when calling bash functions

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

See also my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690828).
So... I have a script:

```
function go_loop (){
for i in `grep -v ^# $1`; do
        $2
done
}

go_loop "/tmp/text.txt" "echo $i"
```

I should have in a result:

```
9
20
21
...
```

But apparently I only get an empty result. How can I feed the second input parameter to the loop?
Please don't advice me do this:

```
for i in `grep -v ^# $1`; do
        echo $i
done
```

I need to make 2 input parameters, first - name of file, second - name of execution command

Comment: If you had worded your problem more precise it wouldn't have been downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to eval the second parameter like this:

```
eval $2
```

and pass it like this:

```
go_loop "/tmp/text.txt" 'echo $i'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `exec` inside your loop, which will run the `$2` as bash command:

```
[root@box ~]# ./test.sh 1 ls
test.sh  tests_passed.txt
[root@box ~]# cat test
exec $2
```

The **exec** builtin command is used to

replace the shell with a given program (executing it, not as new process)
set redirections for the program to execute or for the current shell